# Will Totem be substituted by Banshee?

Tags: banshee, totem

since Banshee now can play videos with subtitles, probably in few months it will gain full dvd menu support, and is in strong development, will it be the time to remove Totem form the default application list? I guess so.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is too early to say whether Totem will be replace with Banshee in the future. While it is a good idea, Banshee does not yet have full support for Video Library management, so it is not really meant for being your dedicated video player.

Totem is more mature, and while it does not have library support, the fact that it is a dedicated video player means it is more likely to hang around for quite a while until Banshee is more mature in that aspect, and able to replace it completely.

Comment: I agree that it is too early to tell.  IIRC, there's been talk about writing a minimal, 'library-less' interface for Banshee, which could make it a better replacement for Totem, in my opinion.

Comment: @MichaelMS: That might make a lot of sense :) - my only problem would be that Banshee is evolving well into a Windows Media Player replacement, and in many ways that will attract converts from windows.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe in this possibility in the not too far, the Banshee to time is becoming a player full multimedia, although heavy consumption features of the PC. And now as the default Ubuntu tends to be more developed, these resources are still assumes no it. But in terms of video, vlc is very complete.

Answer (score 0):

Totem supports playing audio on the fly i.e. when you place your mouse pointer over a music file, it plays it straight away. If banshee can support that I think they might consider.

Comment: That's the file manager (Nautilus) that does that. For proof, open the file manager and go to Edit>Preferences>Preview.